# What are some horror stories of electoral fraud happening due to electronic voting in otherwise established democracies?

Tags: election, electronic-voting, election-fraud

The media is replete with stories of vulnerabilities [real or potential] having been discovered [or likely to exist] in electronic voting machines. What I want to ask here is: what are some of the worst known examples of fraud actually happening due to electronic voting, in countries where electoral fraud is otherwise rare?

Best/accepted answer goes to the story with largest, percentage-wise impact of electronic fraud.

Comment: What about an answer that backs up "electronic voting fraud is as common as non-electronic voting fraud, as far as we can tell"?

Comment: @Caleth: if it's backed up by more than mere opinion it would be a reasonable answer. I didn't ask that question yet (i.e. average comparison) because I thought it would be harder to answer with data than looking for a max/outlier. Usually it's the latter that fires up the press... but in this case I couldn't find much myself.

Comment: @Caleth: there's a paper on India concluding that electronic voting helped reduced fraud over there: https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/evm_march2017.pdf And another one (more guarded) that there was no increase in fraud https://www.rochester.edu/college/faculty/alexander_lee/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/EVM-paper-Web.pdf I'm not sure how widespread fraud was in India (beofre)...

Comment: I vaguely recall something in France. Not very big or important as far as impact.

Comment: Another factor worth considering is the relative ease of concealment of fraud using pre-electronic methods vs. current hardware.    Suppose the power of invisibility recently became widespread.  This Q. might be like comparing evidence of crimes committed by invisible men versus visible ones -- if arrest and conviction rates diminished that wouldn't necessarily prove that invisible men were more law-abiding.

Comment: In Britain we do not have electronic voting, and I believe the US Presidential Election of 2000, pretty well knocked the idea on the head for all time. We use pencils and ballot papers which are individually counted in the presence of candidates and their representatives. However, in recent years, there have been suggestions in the press of fraud associated with postal votes. And our Brexit referendum, is believed by many to have been the subject of Russian influence, in the way that some believe the Trump election was - through social media means.

Comment: @WS2:  The 2000 election was (in the problem area of Florida) a paper ballot, not an electronic ballot.  Mostly Florida was so close that some of the ballots thrown out because they were improperly marked were being questioned as to whether they were or were not improperly marked (the "hanging chad") punch cards... these are not used in electronic balloting for this reason.

Comment: Whatever you call the Yr2000 Florida system, it was vastly less transparent than the voting system in Britain - consisting of a handwritten pencil cross on a ballot paper, and counted by hand in front of candidates, press and public. If it all happens electronically inside a machine, it seems to me that transparency is totally lost. At least that is how it is mostly seen in Britain.